# Is there anything magic about ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: .net, interface, readonly-collection

Having this code...

```
var b = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new[] { 2, 4, 2, 2 });
b[2] = 3;
```

I get a compile error at the second line. I would expect a runtime error since `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>` and the `this[T]` have a setter in the `IList<T>` interface.

I've tried to replicate the functionality of ReadOnlyCollection, but removing the setter from `this[T]` is a compile error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673057.aspx) is implemented with explicit interface implementation, so you'll only be able to access it if you do:

```
IList<int> b = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new[] { 2, 4, 2, 2 });
b[2] = 3;
```

or

```
var b = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new[] { 2, 4, 2, 2 });
((IList<int>)b)[2] = 3;
```

Of course, it'll then fail at execution time...

This is entirely deliberate and helpful - it means that when the compiler *knows* it's a `ReadOnlyCollection`, the unsupported bits of functionality aren't available to you, helping to divert you away from execution time failure.

It's an interesting and relatively unusual step though, *effectively* implementing one half of a property/indexer implicitly, and one half explicitly.

Contrary to my previous thoughts, I believe `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` *actually* implements the whole indexer explicitly, but *also* provides a public readonly indexer. In other words, it's something like this:

```
T IList<T>.this[int index]
{
    // Delegate interface implementation to "normal" implementation
    get { return this[index]; }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException("Collection is read-only."); }
}

public T this[int index]
{
    get { return ...; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do i replicate the functionality of ReadOnlyCollection using explicit implementation. I don't see how you can remove a method or property from the interface.

Comment: @EsbenP: You can't remove a method from the interface... but you can make it only available when the static type of the reference is the interface rather than the class implementing the interface.

Comment: Ok, if I have two indexers, one of them implementing IList explicitly it works

T IList<T>.this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return source[index];
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return source[index];
    }
}

Comment: You've nailed how the indexers are implemented with your latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

It implements IList.Items explicitly, which makes it non-public, and you'll have to cast to the interface to reach its implementation, and implements a new this[...] indexer, which is used instead, which only has a get-accessor.

If you cast the collection to IList, your code will compile, but will fail at runtime instead.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in C#, since writing an indexer in C# involves using the `this` keyword, and you can't write this:

```
T IList<T>.this[int index] { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Lasse: You can write that - with appropriate implementations. The problem is that you can't implement one half explicitly and one half implicitly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You don't have to, if you can write that, you write the setter with just throwing an exception, and then you implement a public this[..] indexer with just the getter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic, the `ReadOnlyCollection` just have different implementations for it's own indexer and the indexer that implements the `IList<T>` interface:

```
public T Item[int index] { get; }

T IList<T>.Item[int index] { get; set; }
```

If you cast your list to `IList<int>`, you will get a runtime error instead of the compilation error:

```
((IList<int>)b)[2] = 3;
```

Edit:
To implement the indexer in your own class, you use the `this` keyword:

```
public T this[int index] { get { ... } }

T IList<T>.this[int index] { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Comment: That was my thought as well, but when i try that in my own class implementing IList<T> it will not compile

Comment: @EsbenP: To implement it in a class the syntax is not the same as the signature shown in the documentation. See the edit above.